# pip install from within scripts in Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x

I've used pip install from within my scripts with the following code in Python 3.7:

```
def pip_install(packages):
    args = [sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade"]
    args.extend(packages)
    subprocess.check_call(args, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)  # nosec
```

Now I'm upgrading to Python 3.9.

Installing the package seems to still work according to the logs:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
...
Successfully installed <my-package>
```

However, when importing a module that uses  with importlib, it doesn't find the newly installed package:

```
job_module = importlib.import_module(module)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<my-package>'
```

What could be the cause of this and is there a solution?

Comment: Generally speaking, the "<my-package>" in the second snippet (i.e. the [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) name) isn't necessarily related to the "<my-package>" in the third snippet (i.e. the [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) name). Are you confident that you have the names right?

Comment: Common examples: `scikit-learn` vs `sklearn`, `Pillow` vs `PIL`, `opencv-python` vs `cv2`, etc

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same names as with Python 3.7, and the pip package name ist the same as the module name.

Answer (score 0):

In the end only restarting the script solved the problem.
I used something like this:

```
def pip_install(packages):
    args = [sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade"]
    args.extend(packages)
    subprocess.check_call(args, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "--skip-pip-install" not in sys.argv:
        pip_install(["<my pip package>"])
        os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable, *sys.argv, "--skip-pip-install"])
    else:
        <code that uses installed pip package>
```